# I do not understand why " options.addArguments("--disable-extensions")" is error in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I do not understand why `"options.addArguments("--disable-extensions")"` is giving an error in selenium webdriver. When I hover it, show command is

```
"Line breakpoint:Chromedriver [line: 11] - main(String[]).-The method addArguments(String[]) in the type ChromeOptions is not applicable for the arguments (String)"
```

I can not fix it.

My source :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Chromedriver {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
      "D:\\TestSW\\chromedriver_win321\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
      options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
      driver.get("https://www.google.com.vn/");
      driver.getCurrentUrl();
      driver.getTitle();

}
}
```

Comment: It's looking for an array of strings not just a string itself. That's what the [] means and why the function name is plural (arguments implying multiple, ergo an array)

Comment: Thank you very much for the review my question.
  I have to fix how, so it is correct? 
I can not still fix it.

Answer (score 0):

@H.Nguyen try the following:

public class Chromedriver {

```
    protected WebDriver webdriver;

   public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\TestSW\\chromedriver_win321\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    webdriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
    }
```